# Rake db:migrate not creating tables on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a basic Rails app where I am trying to use a Google Cloud SQL Postgres database as the backend. However, when I run `rake db:migrate` there are no errors and also no tables created in the GCP database which is our `development` environment.

I can login to the GCP Postgres database through a sql client so the credentials I have work. I am able to create and drop tables through the client.

Are there any details I am missing? I am using:

```
Rails 4.2.11.1
ruby 2.5.0p0
```

Here are the important contents of my Gemfile and database.yml.

```
# Gemfile
gem "rails", "~> 4.2.8"   
group :production, :development do   
  gem "pg", "~> 0.21"   
end

group :test do   
   gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.11" 
end



# database.yml
postgres_settings: &postgres_settings    
  adapter: postgresql  
  encoding: utf8  
  pool: 5  
  username: postgres 
  password: <saved>
  database: <saved>
  socket: /cloudsql/<instance connection name>

development:      
  <<: *postgres_settings 

production: 
  <<: *postgres_settings 

test: 
  adapter: sqlite3  
  pool: 5   
  timeout: 5000 
  database: db/test.sqlite3
```

Comment: Did you do `rake db:create` before ?

Comment: @BTL Yes, ran db:create and db:setup without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading you yml file I can see that in the “postgres_settings” section you don't have the “host” label setted.

In the GitHub link[1] you can find a template to connect ruby to postgresql, these template is part of an example inside of the tutorial published by GCP “Bookshelf application with Ruby”[2].

I hope this helps you, if not please let me know.

[1]https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-ruby/blob/master/2-postgresql/config/database.example.yml
[2]https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/tutorial-app

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `rake db:seed` after Migrating, i do have similar problems on heroku and thats what works fr me

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that did not make a difference for me. It runs without error but no tables are created in GCP Cloud SQL.